# Trouble using WUBI to install Xubuntu. Can anyone help?

Tags: installation, wubi, xubuntu, startup

I am a extremely curious person so I wanted to try Linux, however I have very little knowledge on such a thing. I have successfully installed Ubuntu with WUBI on a newer computer, so I wanted to try it on a slightly older computer. When I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to was incredibly, no sorry UNBEARABLY slow and so I started to think of using 'lightweight Ubuntu flavors' like Xubuntu or Lubuntu (both 12.04 LTS). Using WUBI I tried to install both but both failed the first time they booted up. They would at first load up then work through things like coping the files. Here is where the problem starts. A little over half way through copying files it crashes and comes up with a black screen with white writing and a blurry line through the middle (horizontally). Also the capslock light starts flashing nonstop.I don't have the slightest idea what to do and I am in desperate need of help.
How can I install Xubuntu or Lubuntu using WUBI
and
How can I install (and run of course!) successfully without any of the above problems to occur?
Any answer would be highly appreciated. 
Please help me!
(Thank you in advance)
Drew

Answer (score 0):

First, have you tried booting into the live DVD and selecting the 'Try Ubuntu' option?  If this fails, then 12.04 is not appropriate on your hardware.  Wubi installations do run more slowly that native installations.  The symptoms you are getting suggest that 12.04 is not compatible with your video controller, but booting into 'Try Ubuntu' will test this for you.  If you want to come back to us, please give hardware information including your video controller spec and which version of Microsoft Windows you are running.

Comment: Wubi questions are here if you want to take a look: http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wubi